# How do I recover from Amazon ECS the private key of each node that generated the Terraform script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, ecs

I have used the following repository to create a private test Blockchain and it turns out that I don't know how to recover the private keys of the nodes.  some help? Thanks

GitHub:
[terraform aws ecs private Blockchain](https://github.com/SCB-TechX-Saber-Labs/terraform-aws-ecs-private-ethereum-blockchain)